# Query throwing exception when called from C# Code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have following query in my stored procedure

```
SELECT * INTO my_table FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',''Data Source=C:\TEMP_EXCEL\sheet.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0'')...Sheet1$]
```

It runs fine when run it management studio but throws following error when called from C# code.

> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" does not support
>   the required transaction interface. Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0*

I have set following configuration values

```
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO 
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO
```

And also this

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;**
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;**
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

I have googled for this solution but all seem to have been discussing about making it run in SQL.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Where's your code to do it from c#? Is there a reason you're not just connecting directly to the Excel sheet via OleDb?

Comment: Play with 32bit / 64bit / Any CPU for C# - most probably your architecture don't see your installed driver

Comment: @RowlandShaw I need to import bulk data into database table that is why I'm doing it on sqlserver. Lanorkin what do you mean by architecture? Please explain a bit.

Comment: @Imran: Instead of **OPENDATASOURCE** have tried using **OPENROWSET** ?? something like this - `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0; Database=C:\TEMP_EXCEL\sheet.xlsx; Extended Properties=''EXCEL 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1',

                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')` and yes also show us your C# code...

Comment: @KrishnrajRana, yes I did, it throw a bit different exception
 
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.

And I have tried all solution for this error too that are available in internet.

Comment: @Imran: Have you tried using simple select statement ?? Is it working for select statement ?? if yes then try it for insert statement. but first Let us know is it work for simple select statement ???

Comment: @KrishnrajRana, And I have tried solutions for this error in internet like running above configuration queries, installing access database connectivity tools, providing rights to sqlserver service all the access etc

Comment: @KrishnrajRana yes I'm using select statement to get data into temp table, my above query works in management studio but doesn't work from C# code

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using SQL Server Integration Services for this (rather than writing a bespoke application to handle this import)

Comment: @Imran: If your select statement works then i think you need write query something like this - `Insert INTO my_table(col1, col2) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0; Database=C:\TEMP_EXCEL\sheet.xlsx; Extended Properties=''EXCEL 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1','SELECT col1, col2 FROM [Sheet1$]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to my problem. As mentioned in the error:

"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" does not support the required transaction interface. Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

Linked server doesn't support the required transaction interface, I forgot to mention that in stored procedure I have this query in transaction and it needed to have transaction isolation level mentioned with it so I added ***"READ COMMITTED"*** to my query, whatever was default, it wasn't working with it and it solved my problem.

Thanks all. Your time was much appreciated.

Comment: For anyone else reading I added the following to the top of my SP:
**SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED**

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue, but we had this error after we accidentally upgraded an existing code to use EF 6.1.2
Workaround for us was setting EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands to false just before calling any Stored Procedure:

```
 using (Ef6Context db = NewContext())
 {
     db.Configuration.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;
     // Call an imported SP
 }
```